# Preserve Network Log on Edge

Tags: debugging, browser, microsoft-edge

I am debugging an application on Microsoft Edge and I was wondering if there is a way to preserve the Network Log?

A request is made I need to inspect just before the page redirects with another request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, whether you are using MS Edge (EdgeHtml) browser or MS Edge (Chromium) browser. Here, I am showing you the suggestion for both browsers.

If you are using MS Edge (EdgeHtml) browser. you can refer steps below.

If you want that old request data should be preserved while the new page gets load then you can disable **Clear entries on navigate** option on Network tab of developer tools.

[image]

If you want to preserve the Network log in a file then you can export it as HAR file (CTRL + S).

[image]

If you are using MS Edge (Chromium) browser. you can refer steps below.

If you want that old request data should be preserved while the new page gets load then you can enable **Preserve log** option on Network tab of developer tools.

[image]

If you want to preserve the Network log in a file then you can export it as HAR file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is a great answer!